# Why does java delete my files that were created by the Jenkins P4 plugin?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

Trying to raise a discussion on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072026/how-to-stop-spontaneous-deletion-of-files-and-workspaces-created-through-jenkins?noredirect=1#comment122164248_69072026
The last time the workspaces were deleted, they could not see anything in the P4 logs. But I additionally enabled auditing of files on Windows for these workspaces. Yesterday, the workspaces on the Mac OS were deleted again, and today the workspaces on the Windows instance have already been deleted. I found out from the file audit logs that Java was deleting them (1.8.0_281). And java is used by Jenkins. I got a similar result with Mac OS. Why does java delete my files that were created by the Jenkins P4 plugin?

I moved jenkins from mac os to linux. And I have repeated the situation with the removal. I launched an audit of files and folders on Windows, and the audit showed that it was Java. How can I now understand why java deletes this directory and all its files?

[image]

When they were deleted on the poppy, it was also noted there that it was Java

[image]

How to understand with simple actions why Java does this?

Comment: "Java" doesn't do stuff like that. Some program written in Java does. Probably Jenkins, that seems like a reasonable guess in this scenario. Check the Jenkins logs. Jenkins tends to clean up workspaces that haven't been used in a bit. Do you expect the workspaces of Jenkins build to stay around forever? Then you may be mis-using Jenkins to do stuff that it's not meant to do. Though I vaguely remember that there is a bug where that "old workspace cleanup" sometimes actively acts on workspaces that are still used in a build.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I could not get the information I needed from the jenkins logs, i don't understand what is wrong '$ cat /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
Nov  9 00:30:03 iMac-Macuni newsyslog[22194]: logfile turned over'

Comment: @Joachim Sauer in my case, workspaces that are used daily are deleted, and only those that use the P4 plugin. Those workspaces that are used, for example, are not deleted.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer in this question, I indicated screen shots from the system logs, where you can see which application is deleting the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894772/how-can-i-view-the-logs-or-set-up-java-log-records-where-java-was-doing-at-a-ce