# How can I view the logs, or set up Java log records where Java was doing at a certain moment, and what initiated this action?

Tags: java, windows, macos, jenkins, logging

I have jenkins (master) on a mac os, and java is installed under it. Java arbitrarily in time deletes files created through Jenkins on the machine where Jenkins (Mac) (master) is installed, and on slave machines (Windows), this does not happen on Linux machines (Slave). Perhaps someone knows how to view the logs, or set up records of such logs where it is displayed which application, command, utility, service or process used java, or information about what actions java performed and what initiated this execution with the display of timestamps. (OS Win10, mac OS). Becouse i know time when files was deleted, and can will compare Thanks

Reason: an event for deleting files was noted in the system logs, and the pid of the application that deleted the file was java

[image: event about deletion from mac os]

[image: event about deletion from win10]